# Make an arc match a circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I am actualy trying to make a mini game where an arc should move along a circle.

I wonder how I should proceed to make the "wideness"of the arc match the circle.

Here an example of what I have now :

```
    ringNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.view.center
                                                              radius:circle.size.width/2
                                                          startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0)
                                                            endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                                                           clockwise:YES].CGPath
                      centered:YES];

arcNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.view.center
                                                                               radius:self.view.bounds.size.width/2
                                                                           startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90 - size/2)
                                                                             endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90 + size/2)
                                                                            clockwise:YES].CGPath
                                       centered:YES];
```

[image: Ex 1]
[image: Ex 2]

Comment: they both need to use the same radius

Comment: thank you, but I still can't get it to match it, when I initialize it, I do something like 
arcNode.position = CGPointMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.width*0.4);

And I get a little offset. Can't get the right value to have the arc nicely centered with the big ring.

Comment: try setting them both to an absolute position to verify that it works conceptually. And check if after assigning the position your way the positions are identical. The problem with 0.4 multiplication is that this may place the center slightly off and between pixel boundaries, so try casting the result to int: (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width*0.4)

Comment: Good point, but even with not multiplication, I still get a vertical offset.